# How do i distribute 100 users in distributed mode using jmeter with 3 slaves and 1 master machine?

Tags: performance, jmeter, distributed

Lets say, we have 100 users to performance load test using distributed testing user jmeter. How do I distribute these load among 3 slaves and 1 master machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default each JMeter slave executes the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) transferred from. master individually and independently.

So if you have 100 threads (virtual users) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) each slave will kick off 100 users and actual load will be 300 users.

If you have 100 users in total you could

- go for 33 users in the Thread Group and get 99 total users
- or define the number of users in the Thread Group via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like:

  ```
   ${__P(users)}
  ```

  this way JMeter will read the number of users from `users` property. In this case you can put the desired number of users into *user.properties* file on each slave like:

  - on slave 1 put `users=10` and it will kick off 10 threads
  - on slave 2 put `users=50` and it will kick off 50 threads
  - on slave 3 put `users=40` and it will kick off 40 threads

  amend the numbers according to your needs.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)